# What is the best one-step linear predictor for a white noise?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, white-noise

Suppose $X_i, i \in \mathbb N $ is a white noise. Given $X_1,\dots, X_n$, what is the best one-step linear predictor for $X_{n+1}$, best in the sense of mean square error?

What if the question is changed to the following case:

Suppose $X_i, i \in \mathbb N $ are uncorrelated, and they have identical mean and identical  variance. Given $X_1,\dots, X_n$, what is the best one-step linear predictor for $X_{n+1}$, best in the sense of mean square error?

Comment: I disagree with @user603's comment. In both cases, the OP is asking $$\text{Find numbers}~a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n~\text{such that}~E\left[\left(X_{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i\right)^2\right]~~\text{is minimized}$$ which has the same answer when the $X_i$ are independent as when they are merely uncorrelated. In both cases, the linear-minimum-mean-square-error estimate is just the common mean of the $X_i$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: sorry I misread the question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: do you mean  the linear-minimum-mean-square-error estimate of $X_{n+1}$ is $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)/n$?

Comment: @Ethan No, the LMMSE estimate is $0$ in the case of white noise (which has zero mean) and whatever mean $\mu$ you meant when you said that "the $X_i$ are uncorrelated and they have identical mean and identical variance." I assume that the value of $\mu$ is known. If it is not, and needs to be estimated, that is a different question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: In the second case, the mean and variance are not known. What is the LMMSE for $X_{n+1}$ then?

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in comments, summarized below:

- *white noise* usually means that the expectation is known to be zero, in that case, the best predictor is 0.
- If the mean is unknown (and variance is constant, known or unknown), the best predictor is the (arithmetic) mean.
- Independence? or correlation zero is unimportant here, the answers are the same.